# Swashbuckle/Swagger UI - Adding security definition for APIkey

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, api-security

After some time using my search engine of choice I found multiple blogs and Stack Overflow answers which suggest using "AddSecurityDefinition" when adding "UseSwaggerUI".

This is even recommended in the Swashbuckle documentation.

However for me it's missing...

[image: Missing AddSecurityDefinition]

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.3.0

So am I missing a library? If so which?